# Replace selected Text with String, via Keymap

Tags: lua, neovim, keymapping

I want to replace the selected Text (in Visual-Mode) with the current Date.

Currently I am trying to call a cmd and then use the 'change' method.

```
keymap.set("x", "<leader>nf", function()
    vim.cmd(string.format("insert\n%s", os.date("%d.%m.%Y")))
end)
```

All it does right now is to insert the Date in the line above the selection, not deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom function you need to work with row and column of a selection of a buffer to make it happen. Other option is using the change block from visual selection. See `h v_c`

#### Replace visual selection with date (not `v_c`)

This solution fully removes all text from a selection and inserts a date

```lua
local function replace_date()
    -- Use unpack to give tuple values a name otherwise you can only use indexing.
    -- We are getting line, column, buffer nr etc based on the visual markers here.
    local s_buf, s_row, s_col, _ = unpack(vim.fn.getpos("'<"))
    local _, e_row, e_col, _ = unpack(vim.fn.getpos("'>"))
    local date = os.date("%d.%m.%Y")
    -- Indexing into buffer row needs - 1 because lua indexing starts from 1.
    -- Column subtracts are just to account for start and end scenarios.
    -- We use the positions to fully clear all selected text of a v-block.
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_text(s_buf, e_row - 1, s_col - 1 , e_row - 1, e_col, {})
    -- Place date.
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_text(s_buf, s_row - 1, s_col, s_row - 1, s_col, { date })
    -- Exit visual mode
    vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('<esc>', true, false, true), 'x', false)
end
-- Bind to visual mode.
vim.keymap.set('v', '\\', replace_date, { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

When selection is done you can press `\` in visual mode to change to date.

#### Insert into visual block keeping trailing text

This insert date into visual selection but keeps everything in v-block thats after the inserted date.

```
local function insert_date_v()
    local s_buf, s_row, s_col, _ = unpack(vim.fn.getpos("'<"))
    local _, e_row, e_col, _ = unpack(vim.fn.getpos("'>"))
    local date = os.date("%d.%m.%Y")
    -- Keeps trailing visual selection
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_text(s_buf, e_row - 1, s_col - 1 , e_row - 1, e_col - 1, { date })
    vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('<esc>', true, false, true), 'x', false)
end

vim.keymap.set('v', '\\', insert_date_v, { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

#### Use `v_c`

See `:h v_c` you can replace text by entering c after selecting a visual block. If you use c while in visual mode followed by`\` the function below replaces it. Notice this is bound to insert mode and not visual.
More keystrokes than the earlier solution but maybe less edgecases.

```
local function insert_date()
    local row, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
    local date = os.date("%d.%m.%Y")
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_text(0, row - 1, col, row - 1, col, { date })
end

vim.keymap.set('i', '\\', insert_date, { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

Consider adding leader key to the bindings of above. use `:h` to check out the methods for tweaking.

Any of these should cover your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just can think of this.

```
keymap.set("x", "<leader>nf", function()
    vim.cmd("delete")
    vim.cmd(string.format("insert\n%s", os.date("%d.%m.%Y")))
end)
```

Comment: _Delete_ sadly deletes the whole line and not just the String Selection.